# java 15 jdeps --print-module-deps does not print comma separated list (windows 10, cmd)

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a command to print jdeps output

```
"C:\Users\test\jdk-15.0.2+7_zip_unzip\bin\jdeps.exe" --print-module-deps --multi-release="11" -cp C:\Users\test\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.23.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar -recursive "mytest.jar"
```

in comma format, i.e jar1.jar,jar2.jar,...

but all I get is

```
 org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask -> org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException                not found
   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask -> org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner              not found
   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask -> org.apache.tools.ant.Project                       not found
   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask -> org.apache.tools.ant.Task                          not found
   org.springframework.cglib.transform.AbstractProcessTask -> org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet                 not found
   org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils           -> kotlin.Metadata                                    not found
   org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils           -> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation                     not found
   org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils           -> kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext                 not found
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Update no.1**

```
--print-module-deps
Same as --list-reduced-deps with printing a comma-separated list of module dependences. The output can be used by jlink --add-modules to create a custom image that contains those modules and their transitive dependences.
```

so, I expect the output to be something like this

```
java.base,java.compiler,java.naming,java.security.jgss,java.security.sasl,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported
```

Comment: you might just be using an incorrect separator `,`, which OS platform are you on - macOS, Windows, or Linux?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: using `;` (semi-colon) as separator work?

Comment: It prints the output, but not in a format of jar1.jar,jar2.jar,jar3.jar

Comment: Not sure, if I am getting what is your expectation here.

Comment: sorry, for confusion. Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I understand why I've got this output.

For some reason `--print-module-deps` option also prints out lines on modules which it
failed to find and that is why I did not see comma separated output, if you tried to
use that very same command with an addition option of  `--​ignore-missing-deps`, you
would see a comma separated list.

Comment: but then effectively you don't get to see all the module dependencies, so the logs otherwise are useful to identify what artifact/module is missing from the path

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I was confused on why --print-module-deps does not print
comma formatted output. I thought that --print-module-deps was broken.